# Using react-router with recoil

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, state-management, recoiljs

I have 'react-router-dom' and 'recoil' in same application.

What is a proper way to update recoil state within route?

```
const ItemRouter = ()=> { 

   const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId] = useRecoilState(itemIdSelected); 

   return ( 
      <Route
        key="items"
        path="/item/:itemId/edit"
        render={({ match }) => (

          // TODO: i want to save itemId to recoil state;  
          // const itemId = match.params.itemsId;
          // setSelectedItemId(itemId); 

          <ItemEditor whId={match.params.itemsId} />
        )}
      />
   )}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You already have the state of the selected item Id, it is inside the URL. Why do you need to duplicate your state?

Comment: I use Recoil to manage state of my application, and i need itemId to be updated in recoil atom, because  i have several sync and async selectors that referer to itemId and should be updated automatically. 
But i also want to have some meaningfull url's and  direct links to some features.

Comment: Well you can just set the itemId inside the `<ItemEditor/>` component

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have a component that relies on `useEffect` to update the Recoil atom reflecting the route parameter. Then, other atoms/selectors can read that piece of state (potentially, the `ItemEditor` component doesn't even need to accept the `itemId` as a prop if all of its state is in Recoil)

```js
const itemIdSelectedState = atom({
    key: 'itemIdSelectedState',
    default: null,
});

const ItemRoute = ({ itemId }) => {
    const setItemIdSelected = useSetRecoilState(itemIdSelectedState);
    useEffect(() => setItemIdSelected(itemId), [itemId]);

    return <ItemEditor whId={itemId} />;
};

const ItemRouter = () => (
    <Route
        key="items"
        path="/item/:itemId/edit"
        render={({ match }) => <ItemRoute itemId={match.params.itemId} />}
    />
);
```